# Multiple instance with Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a standalone Nifi process and it have a variable in my case is schoolId to generate flowfile (schoolId is input for my process). This process listening an api and update schoolId when have new id, then it run process and return to me result.
What happend if the api return multiple schoolId one time and it's possible if i want Nifi can run multiple instance with each schoolId receive from my api?(like i have received 5 schoolId, Nifi can run 5 process instance in the same time? or some thing else make my process can handling all them in the same time)[this is my process image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVPU4.png)

Comment: Are you taking about handlehttprequest processor?

Comment: yes, that is my idea, one flow file can handle mutiple httprequest and excute them independent, any solution for this?

Comment: Flow file is a request instance. handlehttprequest is able to handle multiple requests and for each request a new flow file will be created and all of them by default processed independently. So, it's not correct statement `one flow file can handle mutiple httprequest`.

Comment: oh sorry sir, i think my words may be not correct, but my mean like:
I have a process group A and i want mutiple user can use it at the same time and they work independently. User start or stop process throw api and they put their param to process group.
My problem is I only have one process group, if another people want to use it, they must wait until my process gr done or they need stop my process and start it with their param.

Comment: Why you starting and stopping group? Nifi is a flow that normally should run.

Comment: i'm new with Nifi so i think when we don't have any request to process group. it should be stopped and when we have some request to Nifi, we can start it again.

Comment: return my problem, do you have any ideal when you have one process group and mutiple user want to use it at the same time? please tell me some key word or suggest some thing, thanks sir.

Comment: sorry man. i suggest you to edit your question and describe your use-case better - how you are using it now and what you want to achieve. you are saying users providing different parameters - how? nifi is an automated data flow and users  should not work with NiFi-UI (except developers and administrators).

Comment: thanks sir, i'll edit my question

Comment: is there any processor in process group which prevents  you copying  the process group , set the variable and run it simultaneously.  if so, which one and why

Comment: I think my answer should be Nifi Cluster, Each Node performs the same task but operates on the different set of data- that all i want.  Do you think so?  pls comment for me.